# Load Js File from data folder in Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So I have this firefox extension that changes user default search and open new tab in a `bootstrapped.js`

But I need to load a javascript file `/data/sc.js` how can I add that to the boostrapped.js. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There are many different ways to load scripts in addons. [MDN page covering them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_D:_Loading_Scripts)